# Is there a youtube playlist URL format which will play natively in mobile safari and blackberry?

Tags: iphone, blackberry, mobile, youtube

We have some code which displays a default playlist thumbnail and links to a youtube playlist.

```
{if is-playlist=="Yes"}

<a href="http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p={video-id}" ><img src="/_assets/playlist_thumb.png" alt="{title}" width="170" height="128" /></a>              

{if:else}

<a href="hhttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video-id}"><img src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/{video-id}/0.jpg" alt="{title}" width="170" /></a>

{/if}
```

The second link launches a fullscreen youtube player on both iphone & blackberry but the playlist URL links to a desktop playlist overview screen rather than launching the player. Is there a different URL format we can use which will launch a player on both devices?

This is a for a web application, not a native app.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the URL to this

```
hhttp://www.m.youtube.com/watch?v={video-id}"
```

Hope that helps